# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner, I'm trying to make an RSS feed app but every time I try to launch my app on my emulator or phone it gives me these error(s):

```
    05-14 18:25:17.750 2350-2350/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    05-14 18:25:17.916 2350-2350/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    05-14 18:25:18.342 2350-2350/com.gaming.labneh.rssreader I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    05-14 18:25:18.356 2350-2350/com.gaming.labneh.rssreader E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    05-14 18:25:19.266 2350-2364/com.gaming.labneh.rssreader E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaa23b20
```

Here are the classes:

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
Context context;
String address="https://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
URL url;
public ReadRss(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView){
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    this.context=context;
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());

    return null;
}

private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root=data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel =root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items=channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
            Node cureentchild=items.item(1);
            if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds=cureentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<itemchilds.getLength();j++){
                    Node cureent=itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                        item.setDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                        item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                        //this will return us thumbnail url
                        String url=cureent.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        item.setThumbnailUrl(url);
            }
        }
                feedItems.add(item);
                Log.d("itemThumbnailUrl", item.getThumbnailUrl());
    }
}}}
public Document Getdata(){
    try {
        url=new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder=builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc= builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems){
    this.feedItems=feedItems;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_news_item,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    FeedItem current=feedItems.get(position);
    holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.Description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
    Picasso.with(context).load(current.getThumbnailUrl()).into(holder.Thumbnail);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Title,Description,Date;
    ImageView Thumbnail;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        Description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
        Date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        Thumbnail= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_img);
    }
  }
}
```

I really hope you can help me, thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this,recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Comment: please post where you execute `ReadRss` and pass `RecycleView`

Comment: Alright I've updated the post. @shayanpourvatan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your bug is here:

```
Node cureentchild=items.item(1);
```

change it to:

```
Node cureentchild=items.item(i);
```

Comment: sometimes these little things are really hard to catch :)

Answer (score 0):

They are warnings that you haven't attached an adapter to your recyclerview.

If you are going to do long work before you get the data. you should attach your adapter first and then replace the data.

So, you should attach your adapter inside your activity first:

```
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then when you get the data inside `onPostExecute()`; just clear your dataset, refill with newer one and just notify adapter about data changes:

```
...onPostExecute(){
feedItems.clear();
feedItems.addAll(newFeedItems);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

another note: if you keep your asynctask running after your activity gets destroyed; you will get serious crashes since your view would have destroyed. Also, keeping async task as a inner class inside your activity can cause serious memory leaks. provide a callback instead.